# Create shape with depth/3D-look on canvas in Java/android

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

Please see the image below. Flat is the input, the output should be the bottom image which shows the depth or 3D look for straight and curvy lines. Tried the EmbossMaskFilter but that does not give the same output because of the lightning.

I have listed the c# code that generated the required output. **Question is how can I implement similar thing in java/android, especially for a mobile when we need fast processing for canvas drawing**

[image]

```
 Bitmap modifiedPiecePicture = (Bitmap)piecePicture.Clone();
                     ImageUtilities.EdgeDetectHorizontal(modifiedPiecePicture);
                    ImageUtilities.EdgeDetectVertical(modifiedPiecePicture);
                    piecePicture = ImageUtilities.AlphaBlendMatrix(modifiedPiecePicture, piecePicture, 200);

public static bool EdgeDetectHorizontal(Bitmap b)
        {
            Bitmap bmTemp = (Bitmap)b.Clone();

            // GDI+ still lies to us - the return format is BGR, NOT RGB.
            BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmData2 = bmTemp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            System.IntPtr Scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;

            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                byte* p2 = (byte*)(void*)Scan02;

                int nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
                int nWidth = b.Width * 3;

                int nPixel = 0;

                p += stride;
                p2 += stride;

                for (int y = 1; y < b.Height - 1; ++y)
                {
                    p += 9;
                    p2 += 9;

                    for (int x = 9; x < nWidth - 9; ++x)
                    {
                        nPixel = ((p2 + stride - 9)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride - 6)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride - 3)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride + 6)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride + 9)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride - 9)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride - 6)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride + 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride + 6)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride + 9)[0]);

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;

                        (p + stride)[0] = (byte)nPixel;

                        ++p;
                        ++p2;
                    }

                    p += 9 + nOffset;
                    p2 += 9 + nOffset;
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bmData);
            bmTemp.UnlockBits(bmData2);

            return true;
        }

        public static bool EdgeDetectVertical(Bitmap b)
        {
            Bitmap bmTemp = (Bitmap)b.Clone();

            // GDI+ still lies to us - the return format is BGR, NOT RGB.
            BitmapData bmData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmData2 = bmTemp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            System.IntPtr Scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;

            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
                byte* p2 = (byte*)(void*)Scan02;

                int nOffset = stride - b.Width * 3;
                int nWidth = b.Width * 3;

                int nPixel = 0;

                int nStride2 = stride * 2;
                int nStride3 = stride * 3;

                p += nStride3;
                p2 += nStride3;

                for (int y = 3; y < b.Height - 3; ++y)
                {
                    p += 3;
                    p2 += 3;

                    for (int x = 3; x < nWidth - 3; ++x)
                    {
                        nPixel = ((p2 + nStride3 + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 + nStride2 + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 + stride + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 - stride + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 - nStride2 + 3)[0] +
                            (p2 - nStride3 + 3)[0] -
                            (p2 + nStride3 - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 + nStride2 - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 + stride - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - stride - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - nStride2 - 3)[0] -
                            (p2 - nStride3 - 3)[0]);

                        if (nPixel < 0) nPixel = 0;
                        if (nPixel > 255) nPixel = 255;

                        p[0] = (byte)nPixel;

                        ++p;
                        ++p2;
                    }

                    p += 3 + nOffset;
                    p2 += 3 + nOffset;
                }
            }

            b.UnlockBits(bmData);
            bmTemp.UnlockBits(bmData2);

            return true;
        }

        public static Bitmap AlphaBlendMatrix(Bitmap destImage, Bitmap srcImage, byte alpha)
        {            
            Bitmap alphaBlendedImage = (Bitmap)destImage.Clone();

            // for the matrix the range is 0.0 - 1.0
            float alphaNorm = (float)alpha / 255.0F;

            // just change the alpha
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
                            new float[] {1F, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            new float[] {0, 1F, 0, 0, 0},
                            new float[] {0, 0, 1F, 0, 0},
                            new float[] {0, 0, 0, alphaNorm, 0},
                            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1F}});

            ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
            imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix);

            int offsetX = (destImage.Width - srcImage.Width) / 2;
            int offsetY = (destImage.Height - srcImage.Height) / 2;

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(alphaBlendedImage))
            {
                g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                // Scaled image (stretched)
                //g.DrawImage(srcImage,
                //    new Rectangle(0, 0, destImage.Width, destImage.Height),
                //    0,
                //    0,
                //    srcImage.Width,
                //    srcImage.Height,
                //    GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                //    imageAttributes);

                // No scaling
                g.DrawImage(srcImage,
                    new Rectangle(offsetX, offsetY, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height),
                    0,
                    0,
                    srcImage.Width,
                    srcImage.Height,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                    imageAttributes);
            }

            return alphaBlendedImage;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your code shows typical image processing type behavior. I recommend looking at [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) which is Android's high performance compute framework. While you would still need the Java side for showing your Bitmap, your edge detection code would all be in RenderScript. Basically you would let the framework handle the parallelism - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html

If you need it on older devices - it is available in the [Android Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html).

It may help to watch the Google IO video on the topic: https://youtu.be/uzBw6AWCBpU

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please list what type of functions I have to use to get the required output? The above algorithm is no means  perfect because output is bit smudged. What I was after is a way to get similar/improved drawing effect on android canvas.

Answer (score 0):

3D Cube Code is Here paste it into CustomView Class

##### Function

```
private fun drawCube(
    x: Int,
    y: Int,
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    paint: Paint,
    canvas: Canvas
) {
    val p1 = Point(x, y)
    val p2 = Point(x, y + height)
    val p3 = Point(x + width, y + height)
    val p4 = Point(x + width, y)
    val p5 = Point(x + width / 2, y - height / 2)
    val p6 = Point(x + 3 * width / 2, y - height / 2)
    val p7 = Point(x + 3 * width / 2, y + height / 2)

    val path = Path()
    path.fillType = Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD
    path.moveTo(p1.x.toFloat(), p1.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p2.x.toFloat(), p2.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p3.x.toFloat(), p3.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p4.x.toFloat(), p4.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p1.x.toFloat(), p1.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p5.x.toFloat(), p5.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p6.x.toFloat(), p6.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p4.x.toFloat(), p4.y.toFloat())
    path.moveTo(p3.x.toFloat(), p3.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p7.x.toFloat(), p7.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p6.x.toFloat(), p6.y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p4.x.toFloat(), p4.y.toFloat())
    path.close()
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

}
```

##### paste this line into onDraw override Method

```
drawCube(
                    fp.mX.toInt(), fp.mY.toInt(),
                    100 + (fp.mCx.toInt() - fp.mX.toInt()),
                    100 + fp.mCy.toInt() - fp.mY.toInt(),
                    mPaint, mCanvas!!
                )
```

//this is for Stroke(Border)

```
drawCube(
                    fp.mX.toInt(), fp.mY.toInt(),
                    100 + (fp.mCx.toInt() - fp.mX.toInt()),
                    100 + fp.mCy.toInt() - fp.mY.toInt(),
                    mStrokePaint, mCanvas!!
                )
```